# renaming data in a dataframe using config json

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a situation where I need to change some junk data in json such as

```
 'a' need to be A
 'B' need to be B
```

I want to create a config json which shall have a dictionary where the key & value should look like
dict={'a':'A', 'b':'B'}

And then access the json in another python file which reads data from a dataframe where those junk values(keys of the dictionary) are there & change them to the correct ones(values of the dictionary). Can anyone help..?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, given the following `config.json` file:

```json
{
    "junk1": "John",
    "junk2": "Jack",
    "junk3": "Tom",
    "junk4": "Butch"
}
```

You could have the following python file in the same directory:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

with open("config.json", "r") as f:
    cfg = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "class": {
            0: "class1",
            1: "class2",
            2: "class3",
            3: "class4",
        },
        "firstname": {0: "junk1", 1: "junk2", 2: "junk3", 3: "junk4"},
    }
)
print(df)
# Outputs
    class firstname
0  class1     junk1
1  class2     junk2
2  class3     junk3
3  class4     junk4
```

And then do:

```py
df["firstname"] = df["firstname"].replace(cfg)

print(df)
# Outputs
    class firstname
0  class1      John
1  class2      Jack
2  class3       Tom
3  class4     Butch
```